# Separate Backbone View functions into separate files

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, backbone.js, requirejs

I have a Backbone View.

To organize better the code of it, I would to prefer to separate some functions of it into a separate file.

So, I would like to maintains the structure but simply I need to separate the functions into different files:

```
- MyView
   - functions A -> file A;
   - functions B -> file B;
```

I would like to use the view in the same current mode. So I need to call the functions 'A' on my view: `myViewInstance.functionA_1()`

What is the correct way/pattern to implement this?

I use also RequireJS.

Comment: "I would like to use the view in the same current mode" What do you mean by current mode? Where is `myViewInstance` created? What are your AMD modules? Your question is not clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Mixin pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin#In_JavaScript). Divide the prototype of `MyView` to the main part and to other parts, put them to separate modules, make the main module depend on them and merge the parts together.

Add prototype members from the main part to the declaration of `MyView` as usual:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  method: function () {
    this.otherMethod();
  }
});
```

Put the other parts of the prototype to separate modules and export them as object literals:

```
var prototypePart = {
  otherMethod: function () {}
};
```

Make the main module depend on them and merge the prototype from all imported parts either by [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) or by [_.extend](https://underscorejs.org/#extend):

```
// Merging the prototype with ES6.
Object.assign(MyView.prototype, prototypePart);
// Merging the prototype with Underscore.js.
_.extend(MyView.prototype, prototypePart);
```

You will get `MyView` as if declared "in one piece":

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  method: function () {
    this.otherMethod();
  },
  otherMethod: function () {}
});
```

For example, `myview.js` exports `MyView`. It depends on two other modules in order to import other parts of the `MyView` prototype from them:

```
define([
  'underscore', 'backbone', './myview-a', './myview-b'
], function (_, Backbone, myViewA, myViewB) {
  var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // ...prototype members from this module
    initialize: function () {
      this.fromModuleA();
    }
  });
  // Add prototype members imported from other modules
  _.extend(MyView.prototype, myViewA);
  _.extend(MyView.prototype, myViewB);
  return MyView;
});
```

`myview-a.js` exports an object with a group of additional `MyView` prototype members:

```
define(function () {
  var myViewA = {
    // ...prototype members from this module
    fromModuleA: function () {
      this.fromModuleB();
    }
  };
  return myViewA;
});
```

`myview-b.js` exports an object with another group of `MyView` prototype members:

```
define(function () {
  var myViewB = {
    // ...prototype members from this module
    fromModuleB: function () {}
  };
  return myViewB;
});
```